# Code querying a website multiple times not working?

Tags: python, url

Sorry for my limited python knowledge.

I was using this code:

```
import requests

symbols = ["XYZW","XYZW","ABC"]
for s in symbols:
    url = 'https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BALANCE_SHEET&symbol={}&apikey=apikey'.format(s)

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
```

And expected an output of the three different dictionaries, but only got the ABC's data.
Am I supposed to loop it? I'm not sure how to. And why did it give me the last in the list? Does it sort alphabetically?

Comment: The for loop makes a new value for `url` each time through the loop, discarding the previous value.  So after the loop, `url` ends up with only the last url from the list.  Presumably you intended to have the `requests.get()` call _inside_ the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list to store the value on each iteration, and then loop through them to print the results.

```py
import requests

symbols = ["XYZW","XYZW","ABC"]
urls = []
for s in symbols:
    urls.append('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BALANCE_SHEET&symbol={}&apikey=apikey'.format(s))

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()
    print(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

you reset the url every iteration of your for loop. Therefore you are only requesting the last url in the list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).